# how to save print screen to clipboard when using the short-key (ctr+print screen)?

Tags: 20.04

I just transfer to Ubuntu 20.04 from 16.04.
I used to press `ctr + print screen` and then grab the area that I like and then it asks me where to save it or if I want to copy it in a clipboard. But in 20.04 it automatically save it in the picture folder when I use `ctr + print screen`  for print screen.
Is there anyway to use `ctr + print screen`  and then copy the results to the clipboard when I use the shortcut?
I know if I use the interactive screenshot app I can automatically copy that as a clipboard, but I am looking for a way to copy the output to clipboard when I am using `ctr + print screen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot tool that you invoke by default in the Gnome Shell desktop (standard Ubuntu desktop) is `gnome-screenshot`. To have it run interactively, you can use the `-i`option.

```
gnome-screenshot -i
```

In "Settings" - tab "Keyboard Shortcuts", unassign the system default keyboard shortcut for taking screenshots and create your own under the section "Custom shortcuts" to obtain the behavior you want.

For example, if you want to create a custom shortcut that grabs an area do the following:

After going to the tab "Keyboard Shortcuts" in "Settings", scroll down and press the `+` to add a new custom shortcut key:

[image]

Fill in any name, and supply the precise command you want to assign. Then click "Set Shortcut" and when the new dialog appears, press the shortcut combination that you want to assign, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. Finally, click "Add" to add the new keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Im not sure how can I create my own shortcut. I cannot find the section "Custom shortcuts", can you tell me where it is?

Comment: It is "Settings" rather than tools, I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu on hand to test, but is there a section in the keyboard shortcuts list for screenshots? Like in https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZHQJ.png?

Comment: @muru In Ubuntu 20.10, there is a dedicated section for screenshots, but that may indeed not have been the case in previous versions of Gnome Shell. I will adapt my anser to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I can ask your answer in KDE Desktop:

KDE Desktop use Spectacle app for capture screen shots(look at screen shot for Spectacle app)
[image: Screen shot of Spectacle]
and in here if you go in Configure... you can see this page:
[image]
And you can see some Configure mods in here
But I don't know you can install this application in Ubuntu too or not